# Backbone.Marionette Scope issue when triggering the same event multiple times with different arguments

Tags: backbone.js, triggers, scope, marionette, backbone-events

## The situation

I'm trying to render an overview of a nested data structure with models and collections.
In particular, i'm loading a `SubjectsCollection`, where each subject has a few attributes, one of which is supposed to be a nested `LessonsCollection`.

My Controller loads the `SubjectsCollection`. 
Once the `SubjectsCollection` is loaded, the controller then renders a `SubjectListView` (a `Marionette.CollectionView`) with the `SubjectsCollection` and shown in a `Marionette.Region`.

Each `SubjectModel` within the `SubjectListView` gets rendered as a `SubjectLayout` (a `Marionette.Layout`).

Once the `SubjectListView` is shown in the `Marionette.Region`, a function cycles through the `SubjectLayout`'s and triggers an event (`package-definition:subject:layout:ready`) on `App.vent` (a `Marionette.EventAggregator`) for each `SubjectLayout`, passing the `SubjectLayout` as an argument for any Callbacks to receive.

## The desired effect

A method called `openLessons` reacts to the `package-definition:subject:layout:ready` event and loads a `LessonsCollection`. This should happen multiple times (Once for each `SubjectLayout` that was rendered).

Each `LessonsCollection` should render a `LessonsListView` and the `LessonsListView` should be shown in a region in the `SubjectLayout` of the `SubjectsCollection` to which they belong.

The `SubjectLayout` instance is supposed to be passed as an argument to the `openLessons` method, so each `LessonsListView` can be shown in the assigned region of it's corresponding `SubjectLayout`.

## The Code

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
var PackageDefinition_Overview_Controller = Controller.extend({

  ...

  Data: {
    packageDefinition: {
      // attributes: {
      //   foo: 'bar',
      //   subjects: [{
      //     attributes: {
      //       baz: 'quux',
      //       lessons: []
      //     }
      //   }]
      // }
    }
  },

  // Initialization
  //---------------
  initialize: function() {

    ...        

    this.bindTo(App.vent, "package-definition:subject:layout:ready", this.openLessons);
  },

  ...

  openSubjects: function(packageDefinitionOverviewLayout) {
    var that = this,
        packageDefinition = packageDefinitionOverviewLayout.model;
        packageDefinition_id = packageDefinition.get('id'),
        subjects = packageDefinition.get('subjects') || new SubjectsCollection(),
        subjectsRegion = packageDefinitionOverviewLayout.subjects;

    ...

      subjects.load(packageDefinition_id);

    ...

    subjects.isLoaded.done(function() {
      packageDefinition.set({
        subjects: subjects
      });
      that.showSubjectListView(subjectsRegion, subjects);
    });

    ... 

  },

  openLessons: function(subjectLayout) {
    var that = this,
        subject = subjectLayout.model;
        subject_id = subject.get('id'),
        lessons = subject.get('lessons') || new LessonsCollection(),
        lessonsRegion = subjectLayout.lessons;

    ...

      lessons.load(subject_id);

    ...

    lessons.isLoaded.done(function() {
      console.log('Data', that.Data);
      subject.set({
        lessons: lessons
      });
      that.showLessonsListView(lessonsRegion, lessons);
    });

    ...

  },

  ...  

  showSubjectListView: function(region, subjects) {
    var subjectsListView = new SubjectsListView(subjects);
    region.show(subjectsListView);

    // Time to load the Lessons
    subjectsLayouts = subjectsListView.children;
    _.each(subjectsLayouts, function(subjectLayout) {
      App.vent.trigger("package-definition:subject:layout:ready", subjectLayout);
    }, this);
  },

  showLessonsListView: function(region, lessons) {
    var lessonsListView = new LessonsListView(lessons);
    region.show(lessonsListView);
  }

});
```

## The problem

Despite the the fact that `package-definition:subject:layout:ready` gets triggered multiple times, and multiple `LessonsCollection`'s get loaded. Only the last `SubjectLayout` receives its `LessonsListView`.

Also, each `SubjectsCollection`'s 'lessons' attribute contains the very last `LessonsCollection` that got loaded.

So obviously there's a scoping problem here.

## The questions

The questions are:

1. Why do all `SubjectsCollection` get their 'lessons' attribute overwritten with the last `LessonsCollection`?
2. Why does only the last `SubjectLayout` instance receive a `LessonsListView`?
3. How do I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

Well, that's a bit embarassing.. Turns out the problem all along was I accidentally defined some vars in the global scope, such as here:

```
var that = this,
  subject = subjectLayout.model; // <-- should've been a comma... *headdesk*
  subject_id = subject.get('id'),
  lessons = subject.get('lessons') || new LessonsCollection(),
  lessonsRegion = subjectLayout.lessons;
```